Log4j configuration not applying
I'm trying to update our logging infrastructure, but the configuration changes aren't taking effect
The old system was using log4j 1.2, the new is log4j 2.23
I have it building configuration programmatically on launch through a static method, and the logging methods in it to check if it went off are working fine
However, no matter what I try to change, the new configuration doesn't seem to take effect
The log level is still set to Error, and it's not outputting to the file provided
The programmatic configuration is as shown:
ConfigurationBuilder<BuiltConfiguration> builder = ConfigurationBuilderFactory.newConfigurationBuilder();
builder.setStatusLevel(Level.WARN);

AppenderComponentBuilder consoleAppender = builder.newAppender("ConsoleAppender", "CONSOLE");
consoleAppender.addAttribute("target", ConsoleAppender.Target.SYSTEM_OUT);
consoleAppender.add(builder.newLayout("PatternLayout").addAttribute("pattern", "asdfasdf%d{HH:mm} %-5p{WARN=WARN, ERROR=ERROR, length=5}: %c{-2} - %m%n"));
builder.add(consoleAppender);

RootLoggerComponentBuilder consoleLogger = builder.newRootLogger(Level.INFO);
consoleLogger.add(builder.newAppenderRef("ConsoleAppender"));
builder.add(consoleLogger);

AppenderComponentBuilder fileAppender = builder.newAppender("InventoryFileAppender", "RollingFile");
fileAppender.addAttribute("fileName", "../logs/inventory.log");
fileAppender.addAttribute("filePattern", "../logs/inventory.log");
fileAppender.add(builder.newLayout("PatternLayout").addAttribute("pattern", "asdfasdf%d{yy-MM-dd HH:mm} %-5p{WARN=WARN, ERROR=ERROR, length=5}: %c{-2} - %m%n"));
fileAppender.addComponent(builder.newComponent("SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy").addAttribute("size", "50M"));
builder.add(fileAppender);

LoggerComponentBuilder inventoryFileLogger = builder.newLogger("InventoryFileLogger", Level.DEBUG);
inventoryFileLogger.add(builder.newAppenderRef("InventoryFileAppender"));
inventoryFileLogger.addAttribute("additivity", true);
inventoryFileLogger.addAttribute("name", "mil.serena");
builder.add(inventoryFileLogger);

Configurator.initialize(builder.build());

Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(EodidsLogger.class);
logger.log(Level.forName("BYPASS", 1), "Config done: {}", logger.getLevel());

System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.Log", "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger");

configured = true;

This is in a Static method set to run when creating a new instance of the Logger object if it has not been configured prior, but the logger.log at the end is giving the message that the logger is still set to Error
Additionally, I previously tried building the configuration through a custom ConfigurationFactory class with the Plugin tag, but that never ran at all
I'm trying to do it this way through programmatic builds so that the log configuration can be ran in a commons package and kept consistent across the multiple projects in our system

Don't just tell us that there is an error. Share the actual errors. You should provide complete errors. Please read How to Ask.

@aled There isn't an error, the log level and the end of the configuration is at "Error" instead of "Warn" like I set it to

"but the logger.log at the end is giving the message that the logger is still set to Error" The same concept applies for relevant log lines than for errors. Share those lines instead of just telling us they are in the log.

It's a single log line that says "Config done: ERROR". Having that exact line gives absolutely no more information than what I provided in the text.
